# How to remove custom customer attribute in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, customer-attribute

I want to remove custom customer attribute in magento 2 but it's not working. I tried below code but not working for me. Can you help?

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;


 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
 private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
 $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
 }

 public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){
 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
 \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
 'hello_world');
 }
 }
```

Comment: please check and update me https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311086/how-to-remove-custom-customer-attribute-in-magento-2-3/311125#311125

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct but make sure this file is executing on your project successfully. Because "InstallData.php" file only executes once when you install module first time.

Otherwise, it looks fine. Please share your views after checking.

Happy to help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UpgradeData` now.

Create this file Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeData.php :

```
 <?php
 namespace vendor\modulename\Setup;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
 private $eavSetupFactory;

 public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
     $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
 }

 public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
 {
     $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
     $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
              \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
               'hello_world');
     }
 }
```

Change your module version (make sure to increase it) in `Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

Then update your module using command line :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

hope help you

Thanks...

Comment: It is not working for me. @mohit

Comment: what's error showing ???

Comment: Not showing any error. my custom attribute remains same in DB.

Comment: add UpgradeData after you run  setup:upgrade command ???

Comment: Yes i am running that command. After that i am checking attribute in DB and it remains same.

Comment: check my update my answer ...

Comment: Hello @Yousaf check my update answer

Comment: it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

> **First Delete** your Module entry form **setup_module** table.
>
> You code is Right

```
<?php
 
 namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
 
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) 
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
 
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
         $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
         $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'hello_world'
        );
    }
 }
```

> **After delete your Module Entry from setup_module table please run Magento Command**

```
php bin/magento s:up 
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Its's not working brother.

Comment: have you delete your module entry form setup_module table ?

Comment: Yes, deleted that entry and run upgrade command but not working

Comment: have you check your attribute is present in eav_attribute table after doing above work?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am checking from there.

Comment: so brother i think your customer attribute installing code is running please remove that.

Comment: I think customer attribute is installed via other module. Please disable that module.

Comment: please check and update me

Comment: yes it is installed in another module through upgrade data

Comment: So disable that module and do again above answer. Then it's remove.

Comment: Please check and update me

Comment: No its not  working. I don't know why